# Can "noindex" on a post prevent Google Alert?

Tags: php, wordpress, nofollow, noindex, google-alerts

I have a feed of excerpts of specific news on my site. Each excerpt is created as a post, and categorized as "news".

I don't want these posts indexed, or to have these posts generate Google Alerts for key terms or company names, but that is what is happening.

Will noindex on this category prevent Google Alerts for these posts?

Comment: This was helpful to me, but I'm not positive if this will keep it from triggering a google alert:

    `<?php if (in_category('category-slug')) { ?>
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
    <?php } ?>`

Code from this source: http://www.edwardrjenkins.com/noindex-posts-within-specific-categories-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 1):

No index means you don't want your page to appear on google results.

No follow is used to prevent google to fetch the link posted in your website page.

More info: http://www.dashboardjunkie.com/noindex-nofollow-canonical-and-disallow

Answer (score 1):

Here i am giving you some links not sure but may be that'll help you

http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/google-noindex-behavior/
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/J17BUwKe9Ks